# getting the static directory with nodejs using express?

Tags: node.js, express

i have set the static web directory for use in my nodejs app:

```
app.use express.static(process.cwd(), 'www')
```

This brings up all the static files like css, images etc, when im in the root it works

```
http://localhost:8124/
```

however if i go to somewhere like /tags, it deosnt bring up the static files:

```
http://localhost:8124/tags/
```

i get 404 error on the console because its trying to access the www folder
with

> /tags/www/ ....

im not sure how to solve this problem, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to static assets, without leading `/`, this results in appending  relative asset address to the current URL. Instead refer to your static assets with leading `/`

eg. `/www/style.css` rather than `www/style.css`